# How to send email on the click of save button of newform.aspx in the Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I want to send email on the click of my customnewform.aspx while saving data in SharePoint online by using SharePoint Designer..

Answer (score 4):

You can create a List Workflow to send an email and trigger the workflow on item creation.So indirectly when you will click save the item will be created and which will result in workflow to trigger and email will be send.

Comment: Why do you need another solution?  Sunil's answer will achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SharePoint Designer Workflow is an easy method.

Another method, you can send email using Rest Api and bind it to click event of the Save button.

```
function processSendEmails() {

    var from = 'admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com',
        to = 'user@ tenant.onmicrosoft.com',
        body = 'content',
        subject = 'subject';

    // Call sendEmail function
    sendEmail(from, to, body, subject);
}


function sendEmail(from, to, body, subject) {
    //Get the relative url of the site
    var siteurl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    var urlTemplate = siteurl + "/_api/SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail";
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: urlTemplate,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'properties': {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.Utilities.EmailProperties'
                },
                'From': from,
                'To': {
                    'results': [to]
                },
                'Body': body,
                'Subject': subject
            }
        }),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('Email Sent Successfully');
        },
        error: function(err) {
            alert('Error in sending Email: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', processSendEmails);

});
```

Demo about how to send email using Rest Api in SharePoint Online:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36955.sharepoint-2013spo-send-email-using-rest-api.aspx